# HOW TO Pass VB .NET Arrays Hashes to VBA via COM?

Tags: vb.net, vba, com

I am currently trying to pass an array of objects as a result to VBA but Excel is complaining the following:

'Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an automation type not supported in Visual Basic.'

I have looked around on the internet and have seen similar issues but not to one I am trying to do.

My function is declared as follows:

```
<ComClass(Class1.ClassId, Class1.InterfaceId, Class1.EventsId)> _
Public Class Class1

#Region "COM GUIDs"
...
#End Region

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
End Sub

Private Const AT_HOME As Boolean = True
Public Function hello() As System.String()
    Dim a(10) As String

    a(0) = "hello"
    a(1) = "Goodbye"

    Return a
End Function
Public Function CallArray(ByVal serviceName As String, _
                                    ByVal effectiveDate As String,
                                    ByVal serviceParams() As System.Object,
                                    ByRef ArrayRes() As System.Object) As System.Boolean
```

VBA is complaining about the System.Objects my question is how the heck are you supposed to pass and return arrays from .NET to VBA. Also the data that will be in the ArrayRes() is mixed type, its not just strings etc, its an array of arrays that can contain strings, integers doubles etc.

I chose VB .NET because I assumed it would be possible to map to VBA easier.

One last thing, if System.Object and Arrays in VB .NET is not the way, ie maybe theres another way via collections or lists, then Im open to that. I just need to get this data into VBA. Also I could move over to C# if needs be.

Thanks for any help or recommendations

Comment: I suspect the real problem is in the way you expose this function.  Is it actually part of an interface declaration that's `<ComVisible(true)>` and uses the <InterfaceType>` attribute?  Post more code.

Comment: It is a true COM class in Visual Studio under VB .NET, the public function of hello works perfectly fine. So I dont think its due to me not exposing the functions correctly. They can be invoked, but this is an issue with passing datatypes from VBA to VB .NET and them being different at the lower level.

So what I need is which objects datatypes can be passed between or how do to this. I would have thought Microsoft would publish somehtig on this bearing in mind this is their products and being able to pass datatypes of arrays and hashes etc is pretty standard stuff.

Comment: a(1) = "Goodbye".  Post it in your question.

Comment: I added more code to the original post which shows the interface type attribute etc.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it was the data coming in wasnt in the format needed so I created a function to format and process the data